# How do I sorting MySQL result by ages from the birthday date

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say my MySQL database structure something like this.

```
ID     Name    BirthdayDate 
------------------------------------- 
1      John    1974-05-21
2      Peter   1977-11-10
3      Chang   1981-04-01
..................
..................
100    Smith   1945-03-21
```

How to make a SQL statement to sorting age example

```
40 > 45 above
35 <= below or equal 35
```

Let me know

Comment: You're not going to be able to sort into *groups* of the example ranges. You'd be better off calculating `age` and `ORDER BY age`, then grouping then in another language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ORDER BY IF(BirthdayDate < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 35 YEARS), 0, 1),
         BirthdayDate
```

This will show at first the ones, whose age is > 35 years, after that - others

Comment: +1 for the `IF` combined with column `ORDER BY`. I still fail to see the usefulness of the result set.

Comment: @Jason McCreary: me too ;-) But probably OP needs that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

try more simple

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME 
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,BirthdayDate, CURDATE()) > 45
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME 
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, BirthdayDate, CURDATE()) BETWEEN 18 AND 45
```